# Best way to get callbacks from interface

Tags: android, networking, interface, callback, retrofit

The way I'm getting callbacks from network requests is via interfaces.

Suppose there are two classes, A & B. Class A initiates all network requests which are performed by B. When B finishes the task, it has to respond to A.

The way I do it is:

```java
public interface MyCallback {
    void onTaskDone(String successMessage);
    void onTaskFailed(String failMessage);
}

public class A {
    onCreate() {
        B objectB = new B();
        objectB.loginUser(username, password, new MyCallback {
            void onTaskDone(successmessage) {
                //this is called when task is successful
            }

            void onTaskFailed(failMessage) {
                //this is called when task is failed
            });
        }
    }
}

public class B {
    public void loginUser(String username, String password, MyCallback callback) {
        //after task is performed
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            callback.onTaskDone("Successful");
        } else {
            callback.onTaskFailed("Programming is fun they said...");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, if a task is successful the interface methods are called from B which is received in A.

What my question is: Are there better ways to get callbacks besides using interfaces, or can this technique be made better? One issue I face while implementing this technique is, say I'm using same interface with many methods. In a particular case only one or two methods are used, while the rest remain unused, e,g. class B may never call `onTaskFailed()`. Is it normal that some methods are completely unused?

Comment: interface is best way to notify user. another way is you can use https://android.jlelse.eu/local-broadcast-less-overhead-and-secure-in-android-cfa343bb05be and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the question at the bottom: i.e the interface methods going unused.

To solve that I used abstract class! i.e an abstract class will implement all the interface callbacks.
Then while passing callback, simply pass the abstract class instance instead of the interface. This way, only the *required method can be overridden for getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a very good third party library like EventBus
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

You can see its documentation, very easy to use.

```
public class A{

 onCreate(){

  B objectB = new B();
  objectB.loginUser(username,password);  //no need to pass callback

  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
     public void onSuccessEvent(SuccessEvent successEvent) {
    //this is called when task is successful
  }

 @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
     public void onErrorEvent(ErrorEventsuccessEvent) {
     //this is called when task is failed
 }

}



public class B{

 public void loginUser(String username, String password){

 //after task is performed

  if(task.isSuccessful()){
     EventBus.getDefault().post(new SuccessEvent("Successful"));
  }else{
      EventBus.getDefault().post(new ErrorEvent("Programming is fun they said..."));
}
}
```

Your event classes

```
public class SuccessEvent {
    private String message;

    public SuccessEvent(String message) {
       this.message=message;
    }
}

public class ErrorEvent {
    private String message;

    public ErrorEvent(String message) {
       this.message=message;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the advantage over usual interface classes ?

Comment: In software development, we always follow some architecture, like in Advance java for web development, I followed MVC.  Same in Android development, we follow MVP, MVVM etc. In MVP we write every class separately and independently. Also SOLID principle says that a class should have only one functionality. Now Using Event Bus over interface is that we dont need to pass interface implemented class to over business logic class. So our business logic class code is independent and it helps code easy to test and maintenance. I think you should first check MVP and SOLID principle of programming.

Comment: @AlphaTester, you can see your B class is depend on MyCallback interface. it is tightly coupled code. but using EventBus B class doesn't even know to whom it is sending result as callback. You can eliminate interface completely.